# How to change props in a Material UI component according to URL?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

In a Next.js website's homepage (index.js) I have an AppBar material UI component with props `position="fixed"`.

In all other pages I want to set the props to `position="static"`.

I could make 2 components, Header1 (which renders only on homepage) and Header2 (which renders on all other pages), and assign different props to each AppBar component, but I guess there is a better way to do it.

How to change dynamically CSS classes or props in a component according to the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that familiar with Next.js but it should work if you use location, for example `window.location` in React or `props.location` inside the components. A quick search for Next.js suggest something like this

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function YourFunction({ children, url }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const style = {
    position: router.pathname === url ? 'fixed' : 'static',
  }

(...)

}

``
```